# JavaScript - Using an Event Listener with the setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

If I click a button, I want a text to show up in my document after some time. How can I use an event listener with the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: What code you have tried? please provide your snipped code to people be able to know what you want exactly.

Comment: I have posted the answer below, is that answer what you want ?

Comment: Yes thank you very much @Aria

Comment: You are welcome, so accept the answer if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this:

```
document.getElementById('button-id').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('document-element-id').innerHtml = 'the text you want displaying';
  }, 800);
});
```

this uses a timeout inside the click event attached to the button. The value of 800 is the amount of time (in milliseconds) it waits before executing.

Comment: Questions without `jQuery` tag should be answered in JavaScript vanilla. :)

Comment: Could say the same for es6 :P
I'll update the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `setTimeout` using:

```js
 document.getElementById("btnListener").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "I tried 3 seconds to be shown here";
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then message shown.</p>

<button id="btnListener">Show Message</button>

<p id="p1"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome, yes I know you are newbie here, [but take a tour here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I used this also. is it also okay? `var btn = document.querySelector('.sss');
btn.onclick = function() {
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('.hhh').textContent = 'HELLO!';
}, 7000)
}` html ==> `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <button class="sss">
    Click ME!
    </button>
    <h1 class="hhh">
    
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>`

Comment: Yes it is also okay and work.